# Working with CartThrob Packages

Tags: cartthrob, packages

I have a number of questions regarding CT packages, posting here at the request of the CT twitter.

1. If package price is drawing from the total price from the products, is there a tag to output that total price on the template pre-cart?
2. Does CT Price By Member Group work with that 'additive price' feature?
3. Can price adjustments / discounts be applied using the additive price?
4. What happens if a product in a package has 0 inventory?  Can the package still be purchased?  Is there a tag that allows me to reflect this on the template?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these names in the following examples.

- {packages_packages} is the short name of the packages channel's CartThrob Package field.
- {packages_price} is the short name of the package's CartThrob Price - Simple field

I only tested in CT 2.5. I can't guarantee all of this applies to earlier versions

1. This will display the set price if one is set in the packages entry, or will display the calculated price based on the included products.

   ```
   {if packages_price}{packages_price}{if:else}{packages_packages:price}{/if}
   ```
2. I just tested this and can confirm that it works.
3. No. If you're applying a discount based on the entry_id of a product, that discount won't apply to packages containing that product. You would need to include the packages entry_id as part of the coupon's Product entry_id field.

   Also keep in mind that you can't show discounted prices of products until they are in the cart.
4. If a package has a product that is out of stock you will receive the "is currently out of stock" error message. If you want to show the current inventory of products in your package you can use this tag:

   ```
   {packages_packages}
       {sub:title} inventory = {sub:inventory}
   {/packages_packages}
   ```

Comment: Re: 3 - Are there any plans to change the can't show discounted prices thing?

Comment: No plans. It's a great idea, but no plans. It will require some significant changes to make that happen.

Comment: Is there a conditional to detect if a package is 'in stock' in the sense that all of it's products are in stock?  In my application I'm showing a 'buy now' button for in stock items, and a 'sold out' line for out of stock items.  I'd like to apply that to packages as well.

Comment: There's currently nothing in the packages that will calculate the package inventory based on the contained product inventory. I've added this to our internal feature request list.

Comment: I've also just run into a bug where although packages will display the price set in their price field, adding a package to the cart uses the aggregate price, ignoring the price field set in the CT settings for the package channel.  Any thoughts on that?